# Laptop endlessly restarts (because HDD)

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bios, reboot

There are 2 HDD in my Asus K95VM: the main and the additional. I don't know what happened, but the laptop began to restart every 2-3 seconds and not start, I couldn't even enter the BIOS.

Then I found out that if I disconnect the main HDD, the laptop starts and I can enter the BIOS. I reinstalled Windows on the additional HDD, disabled all boot options in the BIOS except the additional HDD. But if I connect the main HDD, again the same thing — the laptop restarts every 2-3 seconds and I can't enter the BIOS.

I don't know what to do with the main HDD and why the laptop restarts. It seemed to me that if any boot option doesn't work, a boot manager tries to use the other.

Could anyone explain? Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a dead hard-drive. Out of curiosity, can you swap the HDDs over? Put the additional one where the main one usually is and see if it boots (rule out a motherboard issue)

Comment: @TomCarpenter I tried, the additional one worked well.

Comment: Sounds like a dead hard drive then. Is it a SATA drive? if so you could try plugging it in to a desktop and see if it works.

Comment: I've had this happen on another different model. What's your battery health like?I've got one with similar symptoms and we're testing swapping out the battery.

Comment: @TomCarpenter I think so too. Yes, SATA. There is the problem — I have only old laptops and Macbook Pro at home, can't plug to them(. Maybe I'll bring this HDD to work and ask admin to check it. But it's not the question. I don't understand if this HDD is broken, why the boot manager doesn't try to boot from another one and the laptop restarts immediately?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the battery is OK.